# What is the difference between y ~ 1, y ~ 0 and y ~ -1 in R formulas?

Tags: r, formula, lm

In R formulas (e.g. for `lm`), which is the difference between `y ~ 1`, `y ~ 0` and `y ~ -1`?

Comment: some of these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366755/what-does-the-r-formula-y1-mean?rq=1) might be helpful - the question is quite close to being a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `?formula` documentation:

```
 The ‘-’ operator removes the specified terms, so that ‘(a+b+c)^2 -
 a:b’ is identical to ‘a + b + c + b:c + a:c’.  It can also used to
 remove the intercept term: when fitting a linear model ‘y ~ x - 1’
 specifies a line through the origin.  A model with no intercept
 can be also specified as ‘y ~ x + 0’ or ‘y ~ 0 + x’.
```

So:

- `y ~ 1` includes an intercept
- `y ~ 0` does not include an intercept
- `y ~ -1` does not include an intercept

The last two are functionally equivalent.